# Windows r2 2012 server - PHPmailer issues

Tags: php, windows, phpmailer

I am running php / mysql on an IIS server on Windows 2012 R2 server . I am using phpmailer to send out emails from the application that is build on that server . I am used to working on phpmailer though i don't have a thorough expertise on the IIS servers.

When i try to run the program , below is the error that i keep getting .

**Could not instantiate mail function.**

Below is my code :

```
$mail->SetFrom('ip address of the server'); //i am using the IP address as the server doesnt have a domain name or an email id

    $mail->Subject    = "TEXT";

    $mail->AddAddress('Email address', ""); //changed in this case 

    $body  = "TEXT 5";

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAttachment("app1.pdf");
    if($mail->Send())
    {
        echo "sent";
    }
    else{
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

If i run it on any other server with a genuine email id of that server ,it works fine . The issue with this server (Windows r2 2012) is that it does not have a domain name or an email id , just the IP address .

Would be great if someone could advice how to go about handling this issue .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not an IP address problem. your 'bad' server is misconfigured and probably has not smtp capability. e.g. you need to install/enable one.

Comment: Smtp is installed and configured..i checked that as well..i am sure about it

Comment: If you are using SMTP, you must [configure the SMTP settings in PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp)

Comment: And with some quick searching, I found [the steps needed to set up sendmail on IIS so PHPMailer functions correctly](http://www.ruhanirabin.com/php-sendmail-setup-with-smtp-iis-and-windows-servers/)

Comment: You're going to need a valid From address of some kind, even if it's just `postmaster@<ipaddress>`; the IP alone is not going to work.